# bash: python3.7: command not found RHEL

Tags: linux, rhel, python, aws

So I have installed python 3.7.11 using this guide: https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-on-centos/

Following the guide worked smoothly but when i do `python --version` or `python3 --version` i keep getting command not found.

```
[root@ip-172-31-95-243 src]# python --version
bash: python: command not found

[root@ip-172-31-95-243 src]# python3.7 --version
bash: python3.7: command not found

[root@ip-172-31-95-243 src]# whereis python
python: /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib64/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m-config /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz /usr/src/Python-3.7.11/python

[root@ip-172-31-95-243 src]# whereis python3
python3: /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib64/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m-config /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/include/python3.6m
```

As you can see above, python and python3 have been installed but the version command is not working.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: if you're bypassing your package manager to manually install something (as evidenced by the linked article) you have to ensure the location it's installed to is in your `PATH` — have you done so?

Comment: thanks for the speedy response! I dont think I have ensured the location is in my 'PATH'.. how would i do that?

Comment: Python should not be installed or updated by hand on RHEL or CentOS if you can avoid it. Too many tools included with the OS depend on the version provided by the OS. The recommended way to get a newer version is to use [Software Collections (SCL)](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/overview). You didn't say which version of RHEL you're on, but RHEL 7 provides up to Python 3.8 in SCL.

Comment: @JamesSneeringer so should i uninstall the python i've just installed then follow the link (https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/hello-world#fndtn-python) to install python properly?

Comment: so i just followed a youtube video and wrote 'yum install python3' which has solved my issue.. probs not a good idea but 'python3 -V' works now and so does 'pip3 -V'